# Which branches of computer science use a lot of mathematical optimization?

Tags: optimization, soft-question, computer-science

My university has a strong backround in terms of mathematical optimization. When you specialize in this field you can choose a lot of sub-areas such as discrete optimization, non linear optimization, smooth optimization, combinatorial optimization and some more. One of my friends at the university said that this is used mostly in computer science. Can you maybe clarify which branches of CS use that a lot ?

Cryptography is quite math heavy but I don't think that it is used there regularly.

Comment: look at google careers, they have dept. called optimisation and they mention a bit about it.

Comment: do you know or se? https://or.stackexchange.com/ cs se? https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I know these but I thought that I ask here first because optimization is a more math heavy field but I can ask there too.

Comment: Machine learning implementation is very optimization heavy. Time is precious and no one wants to wait 3 months for a neural network to find optimal weights.